# Find first element with class, use class to append header element

Tags: jquery, html

I have an unordered list like below:

```
<ul>
    <li class="week6"></li>
    <li class="week6"></li>
    <li class="week6"></li>
    <li class="week6"></li>
    <li class="week6"></li>
</ul>
```

And I am wanting to based on its class add an header element with text before the ul. Like so:

```
<h1 class="week">Week 6</h1>
<ul>
    <li class="week6"></li>
    <li class="week6"></li>
    <li class="week6"></li>
    <li class="week6"></li>
    <li class="week6"></li>
</ul>
```

And the content inside the header element will be based on the class, such as if the class is "week6" the h1 will be "Week 6", "week5" class will output "Week 5" inside the h1.

Right now I am having an issue of adding the h1 tag with the specific content before the ul of the list items pertaining to that class.

Comment: Have you tried to come up with a solution yourself or are you just looking for an answer?  I could careless either way lol.  Just curious.  Anyway, look into jquery selectors and the prepend method.

Comment: I'm having a hard time figuring out the logic and what jquery syntax to use to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("ul").each(function(){
  var weeknum = $(this).children('li:first').prop('class');
  var weeknum = weeknum.match(/\d+/);
  /* Remove if first li is only a placeholder: $(this).children('li:first').remove(); */
  $(this).before('<h1 class="week">Week '+weeknum+'</h1>');
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TGmap/

Comment: Why are you removing the first li??

Comment: @Kierchon The OP was not clear if the first `li` was only a palceholder.

Comment: Is match a jQuery function? I am getting this in the console.
"Object [object Object] has no method 'match' "

And no the first li is not a place holder, it is apart of the list.

Comment: @JustinClarke `match` is vanilla js. Check if `.prop('class')` is on the second line of code in your copy. I made the error of not including it when I initially posted my answer.

Comment: @Mooseman, yeah I added that myself and realized you did also.